# Positioning jQuery UI dialog side by side

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I need to create dialog widget side by side like this as shown below:
[image]

Every time I click the button, it should create a new instance of dialog widget and position it side by side. The problem, when every time I click the button, it always create new instance in the same position (overlapping). Any Idea how I can create the new instance of dialog and position it side by side?

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/wapt49/Q8KVC/1046/)

```
<button id="btnCreate">Click me</button>
  $(function () {
        $("#btnCreate").click(function () {

            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .html('This dialog will show every time!')
                .dialog({
                    title: 'Basic Dialog'
                })
            })
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`position`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) option like:

```
dialog({
  title: 'Basic Dialog',
  position: {
    my: 'left',
    at: 'right+50',
    of: $('.ui-dialog:last')
 }
});
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8KVC/1048/)

Note that this only works side by side as in your question and won't work when there is no more space in screen.